# Why do we have to give database credentials in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

We are using `JPA 2.0` and we created the datasource in websphere and tried to access the database through the J2SE application. We are getting Invalid Username and password error. If we give the user name and password in `persistence.xml` it works fine.

Please anybody explain me why do we have to give the DB credentials in persistence.xml since we have the data source.

Note: Data Source was created successfully and the test was success.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

      <persistence-unit name="Printer">

            <jta-data-source>jdbc/TestDataSource</jta-data-source>

            <properties>
                  <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="false" />
                  <property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="pessimistic" />
                  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
                  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin#2" />
                </properties>

      </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Be assured that IF everything is setup correctly, this just works. A datasource connection is not going to magically behave differently when referred to by JPA, its all the same. So somewhere in your expectations there is something wrong; wrong database, wrong datasource, wrong persistence.xml on the classpath, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the datasource is not configured correctly in websphere. [Test the database connection](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wtelecom/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.twss.install.doc/test_connect_esb_t.html) through the websphere console to verify the configuration.

A [DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) has 2 methods to get a `Connection`. It seems that your jpa implementation uses `DataSource.getConnection(String username, String password)` if you provide the credentials via properties.

The connection properties are intented to use in a Java SE environment. In JEE you should prefer the JNDI lookup. See section [8.2.1.9](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) of the JPA 2.0 specification.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to specify the credentials in your application. Just access your database via JNDI, specifying the name of the datasource you've created in the WS.

One way is to configure persistence unit using the pre-configured datasource (Please double check if it is configured correctly - the test feature is available in WS)

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>
        oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <jta-data-source>
        jdbc/MyDataSource
    </jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If the datasource is not configured on the application container side, you may set it up yourself on the application side. For example, you need a number of the applications each one has its own database connection config.

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:l521:MYSID"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="tiger"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="scott"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Your persistence.xml has the config for both ways. Remove the unnecessary code and try again.

Comment: Apparently that is what the OP was doing if I have to believe that posted persistence.xml file. Note the jta-data-source line there.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more? I am not getting your point.